# Mac OS X: How to get result of otool inside a script?

Tags: bash, macos, otool, install-name-tool

I'd like to change dylib search path in a script.
In the Terminal I use otool -L my.dylib, then see what is the search path and to change it use install_name_tool.
The install_name_tool (-change) uses previous path and the new path as a arguments.
How I can get result of otool -L to a script variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can get result of otool -L to a script variable?

Run otool from the script:

```
OUTPUT=$(otool -L /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator)
echo $OUTPUT
```